# How can I get the epoch from the bottom of the current local hour in Python?

Tags: python

I want to get the epoch according to the bottom of the current local hour.

Example : 11:15:23  should yield the respective epoch of 11:00:00

Here's what I have got so far. **The problem is that there is a timezone difference in the result of 2 hours.** What is wrong here and can it be simplified?

```
import time
import datetime

now = time.time()
print(str(int(now)))
localtime = time.localtime(now)
print(localtime)

epoch = (datetime.datetime(localtime.tm_year, localtime.tm_mon, 
                           localtime.tm_mday, 
                           localtime.tm_hour, 0, 0)
      - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()      

print(str(int(epoch)))
localtime = time.localtime(epoch)
print(localtime)
```

The result is here and there is an offset of 2 hours (tm_hour) that should not be there:

```
1558430139
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=21, tm_hour=11, tm_min=15, tm_sec=39, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=141, tm_isdst=1)
1558436400
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=21, tm_hour=13, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=141, tm_isdst=1)
```

**Note** that I don't want to do a rounding of the epoch to 3600 seconds as I suspect that there had been some leap seconds since year 1970. Not sure though based on my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the the epoch more, I come to the conclusion, that the leap seconds do not play a rule. The start of an hour is always a multiple of 3600 seconds in the epoch. 
Thus the calculation is easy:

```
now = time.time()
bottomOfHour = int( int(now) / 3600 ) * 3600
```